# How to test for backward incompatibility in a distributed system?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, continuous-deployment, backwards-compatibility

We have a Java-based distributed system in which two nodes communicate with each other. Due to regulations, we can't deploy to both regions at the same time. One node can have code that is a couple of hours or even days older than the other node. I need to test this system to detect if there is a backward incompatibility between nodes, so that measures (such as disabling internode communication) can be taken if necessary. These tests should run alongside integration and unit tests during the pipeline builds.

I was thinking of decoupling the deserialization part and send a test request that includes a test flag, to avoid running logic on the node under test. Then run that at each stage of the pipeline between each source and destination node. This would include production nodes since this problem is node- and data- specific. However, I am not sure if this is the best approach. Are there other considerations? Running end to end flow might trigger these backward incompatibility issues which is not recommended.

Comment: Your architecture sounds a bit unique. Typically tests against production services ("prober" tests) aren't run as part of a build pipeline, per se, and it seems like you have a rolling addition of nodes to a network? If so, you might want the node to, on joining the network, send a certain minimal set of test requests to each other node that exercise it's required functionality - and not join if there is a problem. However, to suggest more than that we'd need to know something about *how* a given node would become backward incompatible? API change? Something else?

Comment: You are asking about versions and version based behaviors. Each node must be aware of its current version and past versions it supports; whenever request incomes - either explicitly or implicitly (sort of headers metadata) - a version stamp should be included and node mast match it and choose to act accordingly. Wouldn't it solve the problem?